# How to create csproj command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, code-generation

Is there any way to create a CS and WPF solution of Visual Studio templates from command line?

I wrote a C# and WPF code generator, and I want that my output be a C# solution.

Comment: 1st link on google [Building a WPF Application by Using Command-Line Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @JeremyThompson I don't think the OP wants to *build* the projects, but rather create them from the built-in templates.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I don't want to build my project. I want to create a solution from templates

Comment: @JeremyThompson This url is about command line compilation

Comment: did you ever find a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a Project from command line, simply create and save a Project and use a commandline to copy the folder.

Or using Visual Studio DTE2: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/72d6608b-2e9a-4bc4-b294-b75db17bcad2/

Or to create a Project Template Using the Projectgen.exe Command-Line Tool
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175876(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It seems need a project descriptor file

Comment: I found this url to define project descriptor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175975(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Have you seen [nVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/) or [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to use template engines, and another thing is that I wrote my code generator in python

Comment: [Kicking off the Summer of Love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/?cb=1)... Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, what would be the use of it?

I think you can take a look at the /Command switch for devenv:

```
devenv.exe /Command np
```

where "np" stands for "new project".

Here is a list of the available commands: [Predefined commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx), try to play with it...

But I think it would be much simpler to zip an empty solution and just copy it in your script file instead of asking VS to do it over and over again...

Comment: I wrote a Cs and wpf code generator, and I want that my output be a cs solution