# How to automate creating an ASP.NET MVC Project using Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to find a way to create an ASP.NET MVC application using a powershell command or cmdline. So, instead of going into Visual Studio and clicking "New Project" and then selecting Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web  and then selecting ASP.NET MVC Web Application, I was hoping to write a powershell script that would take a project name and then create the project just as VS would.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create csproj command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598427/how-to-create-csproj-command-line)