# creating, adding files and run a visual studio project from cmd

Tags: c#, python, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I have a main program (python) that will create a c# unit test code. I need to run this code, for which I need to create a new unit test project, add the created code into the project and then run it. I need to perform all these actions from within the main program itself. Is there any way to do these from the program? I mean either running some steps in cmd or using some api? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this may help you create a new .csproj file 
[How to create csproj command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598427/how-to-create-csproj-command-line)
then add your code files into the project directory,and add text like following in .csproj file

Comment: <Compile Include="file1.cs" />
 <Compile Include="file2.cs" />

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.